# How to change AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer frame height and width

Tags: iphone, avcapture

Please help me how to change the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer frame size and

I am passing `Height =100px ; and width = 300px`.
 if i pass the height size 100 than width not change to 300px

Here is code :

```
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 300, 100);
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(20, 50, 300, 100);


    CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    [previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
    [previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:previewLayer];
    [previewView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *prevLayer;
```

Then:

```
self.prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession: self.captureSession];
    self.prevLayer.frame = yourRect;
[self.view.layer addSublayer: self.prevLayer];
```

Thats it.